# Mapping is returning null values

Tags: java, sql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to implement DTO mapping after SQL query execution with JOIN:

Query:

```
public List<Businesses> findCompaniesBusinessesById(Integer id) {
        String hql = "SELECT bus FROM " + Businesses.class.getName() + " bus " 
                + " INNER JOIN " + Companies.class.getName() + " comp "
                + " ON comp.id = bus.company_id " 
                + " WHERE bus.business_owner_id = :id "
                + " AND bus.business_owner_type = 'Merchant' "
                + " ORDER BY bus.id ASC";
        TypedQuery<Businesses> query = entityManager.createQuery(hql, Businesses.class).setParameter("id", id);
        List<Businesses> businesses = query.getResultList();
        return businesses;
    }
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "businesses")
public class Businesses {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(length = 4)
    private Integer business_owner_id;

    @Column(length = 255)
    private String business_owner_type;

    @Column(length = 4)
    private Integer company_id;

    @Column
    @Convert(converter = LocalDateTimeConverter.class)
    private LocalDateTime created_at;

    @Column
    @Convert(converter = LocalDateTimeConverter.class)
    private LocalDateTime updated_at;
    .......
}
```

**!NOTE!** In Businesses entity we don't have attribute `name` by design.

DTO:

```
public class BusinessesDTO {

    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    ....... 
}
```

**!NOTE!** In BusinessesDTO we expect `name` by design and we want to map it.

DTO Mapping:

```
@Mapper(config = BaseMapperConfig.class)
public interface BusinessesMapper {

    BusinessesDTO toDTO(Businesses company);
    .....
}
```

Result from the query:

[image]

As you can see there is a column name.

I tried to use this code to get the mapping:

```
@Autowired
private BusinessesMapper businesses_mapper;

List<BusinessesDTO> list = null;
        try {
            list = StreamSupport.stream(merchantService.findCompaniesBusinessesById(id).spliterator(), false)
                    .map(businesses_mapper::toDTO)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String joinedList = list.stream()
                  .map(BusinessesDTO::getName)
                  .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

But for a result I get NULL or NULL, NULL. For some reason name is not mapped correctly and I can't find why. Can you give me some idea where I'm wrong?

Comment: There is not enough information to answer to this question. I don't understand where is the problem: merchantService.findCompaniesBusinessesById(id) is returning the right values ? if not you should add in your question the mapping configuration of hibernate. If it works you should add to your question the businesses_mapper::toDTO implmentation.

Comment: @Sodala please see the updated post.

Comment: I dont get it. You don't have name in your entity and you want to map a field that does not exist in your dto. Just add it in your Entity.

Comment: @Sodala Yes. Is it possible to implement this without adding it into the Entity?

Comment: Just to correct you I don't have name in my entity and I want to map a field that does exist in dto.

Comment: Sorry I still don't understand :p. The name come from the database right ?  you want to get the name from the database without doing a request to get it ?

Comment: I get the column `name` when I use the query using SQL JOIN with other table. See the SQL query above. By design into Entity `Businesses` I don't have column `name`.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work at all the way you have set it up. 
The `EntityManager` returns your domain objects. 
These have no information what so ever that there where other columns in the select statement. 
Therefore your mapper has nothing to get the name from.

You need to actually return the name from the select.
One attractive option is to use a [constructor expression to create the DTO directly](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/apirefs.1111/e13946/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_constructor).

Comment: Can you show me how to return the name from the select, please?

Comment: Take a look at the link. If you have a problem with that ask a new question with the specific problem you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using tuples? Very handy when you dont' want to add tons of dtos for each query

```
TypedQuery<Tuple> query = entityManager.createQuery(hql, Tuple.class);
List<Tuple> tuples = query.getResultList();

List<BusinessesDTO> list = new ArrayList<>();
tuples.forEach((record) ->
    {
        String name = (String) record.get("name"); 
        BusinessesDTO dto = new BusinessesDTO(name);
        list.add(dto); 
    });
```

Comment: No, is it going to get the name?

Comment: Try it. That query returns whatever the query returns in a list of tuples. You can get an index value too if you like